# Unable to resolve Hibernate Validator messages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

For some reason, I'm not able to resolve Hibernate Validator messages. I have the following in my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>properties.message</value>
            <value>org.hibernate.validator.ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I'm using the `<spring:message>` to resolve the message code. Unfortunately, I get the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank.message' for locale 'en_US'.
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag._jspx_meth_spring_005fmessage_005f0(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:645)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f4(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:611)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:569)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f2(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:505)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:417)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:328)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f0(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:197)
    org.apache.jsp.tag.web.generate_002dvalidation_tag.doTag(generate_002dvalidation_tag.java:109)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.starship.create_jsp._jspx_meth_regula_005fgenerate_002dvalidation_005f0(create_jsp.java:1027)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.starship.create_jsp._jspService(create_jsp.java:598)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:801)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

When I looked inside `hibernate-validator-4.1.0-final.jar`, I found `ValidationMessages.properties` under `org/hibernate/validator/`, so I'm not sure why it's not able to resolve the message.

**UPDATE**

I copied `ValidationMessages.properties` into `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/properties` and modified my `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>properties.message</value>
            <value>properties.ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I get the same issue. Does the problem have something to do with the locale?

Comment: Accoding to the documentation ValidationMessages.properties should be "at the root of the classpath" if you want to replace the one in "/org/hibernate/validator/ValidationMessages.properties". I think you don't need to add it to the spring messageSource bean. Try adding the properties file at the root of the classpath (though it should work with the properties file in the hibernate validator file -- unless the jar file isn't deployed correctly). I've checked the hibernate-validator-4.1.0-final.jar and it has the message you're looking for.

Comment: @Javi, I'm not trying to replace the default one. I'm trying to use it. The strange thing is that this used to work before. I don't know why it's not working any more. You mentioned a problem with the jar being deployed... could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: I already supposed you just wanted to use the default message properties. I jus said to put it on the root as a workaroud until the problem were fixed. The problem I mentioned would be that if you use for example ant or maven script to deploy the application may there be any problem in the script and for that reason the application could not find it, but I think it is not probable because I think it will complain of a ClassNotFound exception. If you user an IDE like Eclipse everything would work if the jar is added in the build path (as I suppose you've done).

Comment: @Javi, I'm using IntelliJ Idea. I'm not using ant. It's pretty strange though - I guess I'll have to keep troubleshooting it!

Comment: I have spring-4. following above steps. still issue is there !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial versions of Spring 3.0.x were a bit wobbly in places, and the new Validation stuff was particularly prone to this.

I recommend upgrading to the current release (3.0.5 at time of writing, which is significantly less buggy than previous 3.0.x releases).

You can also have a chug through the [SpringSource JIRA](http://jira.springsource.org/) to see if any issues affecting 3.0.2 and 3.0.3 sound like your particular problem.

Comment: I just rolled-back the edit. It looked like it still wasn't able to resolve messages. I am trying to compare the old and new projects to see what's different. Thanks for the link to JIRA - will take a look at it and I'll also try to update to 3.0.5

Comment: This was it. The update to 3.0.5 got rid of the error messages! Thanks a bunch. I've been pulling my hair out for a while!